# Ruby on Rails: Change checkbox label in formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, has-and-belongs-to-many, formtastic

I am using formtastic to render a form for a object of a model that has a HABTM relationship with another model.

I am doing this to render a list of checkboxes:

```
<%= f.input :classes, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => UserClass.all %>
```

And yes, it renders all the checkboxes and at the right side it shows the object name, something like this. So I have something like this:

```
[x] #<UserClass:0x000000087e4958>
```

How can I change that? I want to show the class name and description...

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `:member_label` option:

```
<%= f.input :classes, :as => :check_boxes,
    :collection => UserClass.all, :member_label => :name %>
```

(Assuming your UserClass has a `name` attribute, for example). If your label comes from multiple fields, you can pass a Proc. For example (if your UserClass has `first_name` and `last_name` attributes):

```
<%= f.input :classes, :as => :check_boxes,
    :collection => UserClass.all,
    :member_label => Proc.new { |u| "#{u.first_name} #{u.last_name}" } %>
```

The above is for Formtastic version 2.x. For the 1.2-stable branch, it works the same (you can pass in a method name or proc) but the option is called `:label_method`. Example:

```
<%= f.input :classes, :as => :check_boxes,
    :collection => UserClass.all, :label_method => :name %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  I have tried that, and also the :value_method, but I still see the #<UserClass:0x000000087e4958> . Any thoughts?

Comment: @HommerSmith, in 1.2 the option was called `:label_method`. I updated my answer to incldue that.

Comment: Awesome! Why have they changed the name of that option that much? :P

Comment: @HommerSmith, For the transition from version 1 to version 2, the code was heavily gutted and massively re-factored. Just one change among the storm.

Answer (score -1):

TRemove the render from the tag.
Use <% instead of <%=

thanks @HommerSmith for clearing things up regarding the use in older versions and where to use the above example.

Comment: @HommerSmith, Galuga is right. In version 1.2 you omit the `=`, the render is build in. But also see my answer for how to do what you want in 1.2.

Comment: @HommerSmith, hmm... I thought it did the render automatically, but if not, I guess just keep using the `<%=` ;)

Comment: @HommerSmith, actually nevermind. You were right from the start, you *do* need `<%=`, you only omit it from `form.inputs`, not from `form.input`. But note that this *is* different from the newer version, where you use `<%=` even for `form.inputs`.

Comment: @Ben Lee Ok. Thanks for your time and accurate answer.